# How to print barcode using Android Java to zebra ez320?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I have no idea how to solve the problem so if someone succeeded to print an barcode with the EZ320 and can share the code, it should help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code

Comment: I tried this link https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/P25Demo...But doesnt print barcodes.

Comment: I tried this link also https://github.com/AlexanderKaraberov/Android-BluetoothPrinter-Demo

Answer (score 1):

I can show you how I print labels via Bluetooth on a Zebra printer, including a 2 of 5 barcode. The printing language is CPCL and needs to be set in the printer firmware via the printer utilities.

The singleton class:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.BluetoothConnection

object PrinterUtil {

    fun printCpcl(
        bDevice: BluetoothDevice,
        str1: String,
        str2: String,
        str3: String,
        str4: String,
        str5: String
    ) {
        Thread(Runnable {
            try {
                val printerConnection = BluetoothConnection(bDevice.address)
                Looper.prepare()
                printerConnection.open()
                val cpclData = "! 0 200 200 700 1\r\n" +
                        "LABEL\r\n" +
                        "PAGE-WIDTH 700\r\n" +
                        "COUNTRY USA\r\n" +
                        "BARCODE I2OF5 2 2 100 70 135 " + str1 + "\r\n" +
                        "ST TT0003M_.TTF 16 16 86 240 " + str1 + "\r\n" +
                        "ST TT0003M_.TTF 15 16 70 9 str2: " + str2 + "\r\n" +
                        "ST TT0003M_.TTF 12 16 70 70 " + str3 + "\r\n" +
                        "ST TT0003M_.TTF 13 16 320 177 Str4: " + str4 + "\r\n" +
                        "ST TT0003M_.TTF 14 16 320 127 Str5: " + str5 + "\r\n" +
                        "FORM\r\n" +
                        "PRINT\r\n"
                if (printerConnection.isConnected) {
printerConnection.write(cpclData.toByteArray())
                    Thread.sleep(500)
                    printerConnection.close()
                    Looper.myLooper().quit()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
}
        }).start()
    }
}
```

Call method in Activity:

```
private var btList = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().bondedDevices.toMutableList()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(getContentView())
        try {
                    PrinterUtil.printCpcl(
                        btList[0],
                        str1,
                        str2,
                        str3,
                        str4,
                        str5
                    )
                } catch (e: ConnectionException) {
                    Log.d(null, "failed to print...")
                }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this post it helps alot. Do you have complete source code?

Comment: This is the complete source code. I use Zebra printers from the ZQ-series and it works on every printer - so this means I don't make any changes on the code.

In case you need more documentation, pay attention to this document - you can get needed information about the CPCL printing language from here.

[link](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/comtec/PROMAN-CPCL_RevY.pdf)

Have you already seen the support site from Zebra about this printer yet?

[link](https://www.zebra.com/cn/zh/support-downloads/printers-cn/ez320.html)

Comment: Thanks, how can i integrate your posted code to my Android Java application?

Comment: If you work with Android Studio and your project is written in Java, you are still able to add a Kotlin file to it. Follow [this manual](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin), how to do this. 
Please don't forget to accept my answer if it works for you.